# mailto: with attachment, body, to coming from MVC4 controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I have been asked to provide a link for each entry in a MVC4 Webgrid table that will open an email in outlook, with to, body and and attachment filled in.  Now mailto: link seemed like an option but cannot have the data on every row in the table, it would be huge.  So I was wondering can anyone help me in how I could get this information when the link is clicked, maybe json?

Or is there a way of generating it in the controller and triggering a launch from there similar to doing a FileStreamResult?